# Past Progressive + BEFORE/AFTER + Gerund

Tags: grammar, gerunds, past-continuous

> 1. Tom Cruise **was thinking** of a career in the church **before finding** job in the movies.
> 2. Tom Cruise **wasn't thinking** of a career in the church **after finding** job in the movies.

Please tell me, why is Past Continuous used here? I was tought that a normal variant of this sentence is:

> 3. Tom Cruise **thought** of a career in the church **before finding** job in the movies.

Or that is because of the gerund "finding"? I mean if for example I wrote the sentence like this:

> 4. Tom Cruise **thought** of a career in the church **before he found** job in the movies.

Comment: As a side note, you should be using an indefinite article in all of those sentences: ***a*** *job*. Also, the indefinite article aside, *all* of those sentences are grammatical and normal.

Comment: @Jason Bassford, thanks for correcting! But what is the difference between them? I guess that Continuous is used for emphasizing. Isn't it? Or it changes the senses?

Comment: @Jason Bassford I start thinking that #3 is not correct. Because of the gerund after "before". Maybe there is some rule that tells us something like "-ing with -ing" and "simple past with simple past"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Was thinking of” vs “thought of”- when you think about something, there is no definite start and end point, so either the past continuous (progressive) or the simple past is fine. In other words, “to think of (or about)” in this context is something that takes time, so the simple past can be thought of as having this sense of happening over time built into it.

Either “before he found” or “before finding” works here, and they are interchangeable. It doesn’t matter what version of “to think” you use. You could also say

> Tom Cruise was thinking about a career in the church before he found a job in the movies.

Comment: Thanks, now after all I got it! But what does it mean " happening over time built into it"? Time built into what?

Comment: @user79871 Maybe I didn’t phrase that well. I just meant that when you think about something, it takes time. I was trying to say that the term “thought of” implies “thought about for a period of time.” So it’s not very different from “was thinking of,” which you know is over a period of time, since it’s the past progressive tense.